# Form validation in Jquery sets background color for entire form and not form elements

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form that on submit needs to be validated using jQuery. Usually I would just use the jQuery validate plugin but unfortunately cannot use it in this case as error message are not required, just styling changes.

Consider the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    $('.submitJobform').on('submit', function(e) {
        if( !$('.required').value ){
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
        }

        e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
    });
 });
```

When pressing the submit button, if a textfield with the .required class does not have a value, the entire form background turns red. I thought using the $this keyword would select the current value that has been found to contain no value however this is not the case. Is there any way of forcing the $(this) to refer to the text item in question or is there an alternate method so that only the background of the text field goes red?

Thanks in advance

Jezzipin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.submitJobform').on('submit', function (e) {
    $('.required').each(function () {
        if (!this.value) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent form from submitting
});
});
```

Comment: Best and most complete answer so far. Thanks.

Comment: This will throw an error if you don't delete that extra `});` at the last line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this however keep this thing in mind that it will work only if your form have only one required element.
If you have multiple required elements which have "required" class then you have to run **foreeach** for the selector and process each element accordingly.

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
    $('.submitJobform').on('submit', function(e) {
        $( ".required" ).each(function( index ) {
            if( !$(this).value ){
               $(this).css('background-color','red');
            }
          });

        e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
    });
 });
```

Comment: I have more that one .required element hence why I have used a class. Could you please demonstrate the foreach method in question?

Comment: check it now, you can use $.each here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.submitJobform').on('submit', function(e) {
    if( !$('.required').value ){
        $('.required').css('background-color','red');
    }

    e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
});
```

Or if you have more than one class `.required`, you can do:

```
$('.submitJobform').on('submit', function(e) {
    $('.required').each(function() {
        if( !$(this).value ){
            $(this).css('background-color','red');
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `this` variable belongs to the form since the form gets submitted and therefore the function gets called. To check for inputs, you need to need to look through them:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.submitJobform').on('submit', function(e) {

        // here this is the form
        $(this).find('.required').each(function() {
            // here this is the current element matched in the each loop
            var input = $(this);

            if (!input.val()) input.css('background-color','red');
        });

        e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> "**Usually I would just use the jQuery validate plugin** but unfortunately
>   cannot use it in this case as error message are not required, just
>   styling changes."

You can easily turn off validation messages while using the jQuery Validation plugin. Simply placing a `return false` within the `errorPlacement` callback function will kill the messages. Then style the `.error` class as desired with CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.submitJobform').validate({
        // rules, options & callbacks,
        errorPlacement: function() {
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/eKbmZ/1/

Comment: Using the jQuery validate plugin in this situation would be overkill. I would use it there were multiple forms in my site but that is not the case in this situation.

Comment: @jezzipin,  that's not what you said in your OP:  _"Usually I would just use the jQuery validate plugin but unfortunately cannot use it in this case as error message are not required, just styling changes."_